# Snowflake Stored Procedure failure in Airflow

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am executing a Snowflake Stored Procedure in Airflow dag, the SSP executes without any failure in Snowflake but it fails at create statement while running in Airflow DAG.

> `call dynamic_view_on_table_sp('DIM_LEXIDS_PROVIDER');`

Error I am getting in airflow:

> ```
> JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in DYNAMIC_VIEW_ON_TABLE_SP at '                      create_statement += "' position 42
> ```

I tried using backticks and double quotes for SQL statements at different places. Below is the working code in Snowflake (failing in Airflow). Please someone help me with this error

```
create or replace procedure dynamic_view_on_table_sp(TABLEPREFIX VARCHAR)
            returns STRING
            language javascript
            as     
            $$
              var get_tables_name_stmt = "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name like UPPER('"+ TABLEPREFIX + "%');"
              var get_tables_name_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:get_tables_name_stmt });
              var tables = get_tables_name_stmt.execute();
              var row_count = get_tables_name_stmt.getRowCount();
              var cnt = 0; 
              var create_statement = `create or replace view dim_full_segment_lexids_tables_vw as \n`;
              while (tables.next())  {
                  cnt += 1;
                  var table_name = tables.getColumnValue(1); 
                  create_statement += `select * from ` + table_name 
                  if (cnt < row_count){
                      create_statement += "\n union all \n"
                  }
               }
              var create_view_statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: create_statement} );
                create_view_statement.execute();
              return create_view_statement.getSqlText();
            $$;
```

Comment: You’ve declared this var twice: get_tables_name_stmt

Comment: Thankyou so much! It worked. Appreciate it!